# Check how long request has been in IIS queue from within VB.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, logging, asp.net-web-api

I am coming across the problem that we are able to monitor IIS queue lengths, but we can't tell from within the application how long a request has been sat there.

That means that when we log our response time, we are logging just the application response time, whereas what is more important to us is the amount of time the user at the other end has been waiting (which will include waiting on IIS queue).

I've had a good browse through the request object and can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mark